# Mathematical equation for a generalized linear mixed model with interactions

Tags: mixed-model, mathematical-statistics, glmm

I'd like to know how following R-code for a binomial GLMM (package lme4) translates into a proper mathematical notation form?

```
glmer(Y ~ Var1*Var2*Var3+(Var1+Var2+Var3|i) , family=”binomial”, data=df)
```

maybe something like:

$$
logit(Y_i)  = α + β_{Var1} Var1 × β_{Var2} Var2 × β_{Var3} Var3 + a_i +b_{i Var1} Var1 + b_{i Var2} Var2 +b_{i Var3} Var3 + ε_i
$$

Comment: The main effects and the pairwise interactions are missing (as a start)

Comment: You should note carefully the meaning of `*` in an R-formula, which is quite different from $\times$ in an ordinary expression as written by hand (for which the R-formula equivalent is actually `:`).