# Mathematical notation for glmer (GLMM)?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm looking for the mathematical notation equivalent of:

```
glmer(ret15i~AARC_Ret+(1|METRO)+ret02i)
```

I have a model; it is neither a HLM nor a GLM, but both. It is referred to (variously) as a hierarchical generalized linear model, a generalized linear mixed model, a multi-level non-linear mixed effect model, etc. Generalized Linear Models require a link function. The hierarchical nature of my data means I'll have both fixed and random effects. I know what distribution I'm using: Poisson. As formulated in R, [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/what-is-a-difference-between-random-effects-fixed-effects-and-marginal-model/241950#241950) suggests my random effects are limited to random intercept.

---

From: STATA Multilevel Mixed Effects Reference Manual Release 13.

Comment: A similar question, with no answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74318/mathematical-equation-for-a-generalized-linear-mixed-model-with-interactions

Comment: Good explanation of Random vs. fixed effects and their notation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/what-is-a-difference-between-random-effects-fixed-effects-and-marginal-model/241950#241950

Comment: Related wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_generalized_linear_model

Comment: The formula you have there won't work (there's an extra parenthesis, and `+|` isn't allowed).  Should it be `glmer(ret15i ~ AARC_Ret + (1|METRO) + ret02i, family=poisson)` ?

Comment: Do you have multiple measurements of ret15i for each METRO and if yes, how many? Are these counts collected over time or space?  If over time/space, is the time/area span underlying each count the same across multiple counts for a given level of METRO? How many levels does METRO have? Are AARC_Ret and ret02i continuous/discrete?   Are the values of AARC_Ret and ret02i changing over time for a given level of METRO? In my view, one would need to know all of this before suggesting a mathematical notation for your specific model.

Comment: Ret15i is Retail employment in 2015; ret02i is retail employment in 2002. I have multiple measurements within each metro, each representing a single transit station. Both are counts. AARC is continuous/discrete. METRO is a factor (grouping) variable.

Answer (score 0):

GLMM notation:

This is the best thing I've found so far (on the internet). 
[image]

> "Generalized linear mixed models are typically constructed by
>   incorporating random effects into the linear predictor of a
>   conditionally independent exponential family model. I now formalize
>   that notion with the following definition of a generalized linear
>   mixed model:  In this definition we see the usual ingredients of a
>   generalized linear model. First, the distribution of Yi from an
>   exponential family (in this case the distribution is assumed to hold
>   conditional on the random effects u). Second, a link function, g(-) is
>   applied to the conditional mean of Yi given u to obtain the
>   conditional linear predictor. Finally, the linear predictor is assumed
>   to consist of two components, the fixed effects portion, described by
>   x'13 and the random effects portion, z'u, for which a distribution is
>   assigned to u"

McCulloch, C. E., & Neuhaus, J. M. (2014). Generalized linear mixed models. Wiley StatsRef: Statistics Reference Online.

Comment: It would help if you could indicate whether you would still like a general formulation for Poisson mixed effects models or a specific formulation for your own model.  In general, people answer their own question only if nobody else has done so and/or they figured out the answer all by themselves after posting the initial question.  I think answering your own question may inadvertently suggest that you are no longer seeking an answer from member of this forum.

Comment: I was hoping someone would provide a better answer, and I could upvote that. So yes, I am still seeking such a formulation. Or perhaps derivation is the proper word?